# How would I measure Bouillon Cubes compared to the actual powder

Tags: bouillon, cubes

Is there a standard measurement that can be used?

Comment: There are so many types of both... so I'd choose a general workaround (see the answer). Considered downvoting the question but didn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bouillon cubes I am familiar with are equal to 1 teaspoon of powder.

Answer (score 6):

I'd figure it backwards. You need x amount of Bouillon. You can see (from the specific powder AND the specific cubes) how much you'll need of each to make that x amount.

Then calculate the ratio based on those numbers.

Then cook, and discover there's a taste difference, and correct accordingly. :)

Comment: Generally, they tell you that one cube should be combined with X cups of water. Powdered boullion is 1 teaspoon per cup, usually. If a boullion cube says to dissolve in 2 cups of water, then it's the equivalent of two teaspoons.

Answer (score 0):

The bouillon cubes I use (Wyler's) states on the jar that one cube makes ONE cup of broth.
Crushed one to see how it measured up and it came to one teaspoon. Also the reliable sources I've checked all say one cube = 1 teaspoon (tsp). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Wyler's website under "tips". They state that one boullion cube = one teaspoon of powder.